# Stopping mathematica from rearranging elements in a list

Tags: functions

I have the following list

```
set1={-(1/x), -(1/x) + x/2 - 2 Log[x] - Log[x]/x, 1}
```

How when I am doing

```
Complement[set1, {-1/x}]
```

Then it gives

```
{1, -(1/x) + x/2 - 2 Log[x] - Log[x]/x}
```

then it rearranges the third element to the second element and vice versa. This is dangerous for my case. How to stop this?

Comment: `Complement`, `Union`, `Intersection` treat the list as a set. Hence duplicates are deleted and a sort is performed.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `DeleteElements` which came with V 13.1:

```
set1 = {-(1/x), -(1/x) + x/2 - 2 Log[x] - Log[x]/x, 1}

DeleteElements[set1, {-1/x}]
```

[image]

Versions prior to 13.1 could use f.e.

```
Delete[set1, Position[set1, -1/x, 1]]
```

or (since V 12.1)

```
SubsetReplace[set1, {-1/x} -> Nothing]
```

Both give the expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
UniqueElements[{set1,{ -1/x}}][[1]]

(* {-x^(-1)+x/2-2*Log[x]-Log[x]/x,1} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
set1 = {-1/x, -1/x + x/2 - 2 Log[x] - Log[x]/x, 1};

Fold[DeleteCases, set1, {-1/x}]
(*    {-1/x + x/2 - 2 Log[x] - Log[x]/x, 1}    *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of applying "Complement" to the whole list set1, you may apply it to the single elements of set1 like:

```
set1 = {-(1/x), -(1/x) + x/2 - 2 Log[x] - Log[x]/x, 1};
Complement[{#}, {-1/x}] & /@ set1 // Flatten

{-(1/x) + x/2 - 2 Log[x] - Log[x]/x, 1}
```

Answer (score 3):

or use filter, in Mathematica it's Select

```
{-(1/x), -(1/x) + x/2 - 2 Log[x] - Log[x]/x, 1} //
Select[# =!= -1/x&]
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, this is what you need

```
set1 = {-(1/x), -(1/x) + x/2 - 2 Log[x] - Log[x]/x, 1}
SortBy[Complement[set1, {-1/x}], Position[set1, #] &]
```